# Was there any specific motivation for the "Shanghai Fugu Agreement"?

Tags: germany

On a wiki walk from the Wikipedia article on [Fugu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugu), I came across the [Shanghai Fugu Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_Fugu_Agreement):

> The Shanghai Fugu Agreement (German: Shanghaier Kugelfisch-Abkommen)
>   was a successful 1985 political prank played on the Social Democrats
>   in the German state of Hesse.
>
> ...
>
> The Greens argued that the fugu fish is well known to be a dangerous
>   delicacy requiring specialized chefs who mostly come from Asia. Due to
>   expanding restrictions on work permits restaurants have found it
>   difficult to employ such specialists. The "Shanghai Fugu Agreement"
>   was supposed to provide special regulations for certified fugu chefs
>   internationally.

Was there any specific motivation for this prank?

Were the Greens in any way trying to refer to the [Fugu plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugu_Plan), which involved Japan accepting Jews fleeing nazi Germany, which involved Shanghai?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any specific evidence to back that but to me it sounds more like a way for the Greens to express their difference with established parties than anything else.

You have to realize that the party came from all the student protests and civil initiatives that emerged after 1968. Some members came from strongly anti-authoritarian social movements, others had been active in revolutionary militant groups (Joshka Fisher himself was involved in attacks on police officers) and this coalition was the first time ever they participated in a government or anything similar.